# Can't find my iOs build in iTunes Connect after upload by Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, software-distribution

i'm trying to upgrade an iOs App on the App Store by releasing a new version. I've the iTunes Connect Account and I'm working on Xcode.

I've updated the Version and Build values from `1.0.15` to `1.0.16` in the Identity Section of my app *-Info.plist

[image: Xcode Build Version]

Then I uploaded the build to the iTunes Connect from Xcode by doing:
Product -> Archive -> Validate -> and then `Upload to the App Store...`->
I selected the `automatic signing authentication` and chosen the App Team for profiling that I want the build to be uploaded to.

Xcode has uploaded the build to the iTunes Connect and no error have been thrown.

Now, when I go to my iOs build on the App Store, I expect to find it, but there isn't.

[image: No build here]

When I upload it again I now have this error:

[image: Redundant binary upload]

It seems that the Apple Server already got the release.

**So? Where is my build gone? How can I found it?**

I read in some SO threads that there was a Prerelease View in the iTunes Connect but I'm unable to find it any more. Maybe it has been replaced?

**EDIT 1**

This is my Build iOs on iTunes Connect view.

[image: No new build here]

The open tab is the previous build, my new one `1.0.16` it is not present in the list and I can't find it anywhere..

I knew that I could upload a newer version by incrementing the version and build.

If it will not appear soon I will assume an error occurred and try to submit a new one.

***EDIT 2***

One week has passed and the build hasn't appeared. So I have uploaded a new upgraded version to `1.0.17`, but it's still not appearing in my `activity` tab.

[image: itunes connect]

I would like to point out that before loading the previus 1.0.16 version, I had already created a new app version in the App Store Tab.

Can this possibly causes the issue?

[image: no build]

[image: itunes]

**What else can it be?**

I'm gonna wait a little more and if not appearing i'll open a support ticket.

Comment: Usually it takes some time to reflect in iTunes connect. It always appears later. If you are still circumspect, then you can upload again by incrementing the version.

Comment: Same problem for me. I solved by uploading a new binary with build number increased

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Solution: **check your email !**

After days of waiting I discovered that my iTunes Connect associated email address had received feedback from the iTunes Store Team. The emails said there was issues on the app (Missing Info.plist key) that prevented the delivery to be processed.

It is important to check your email address from apple communications because some of that information cannot be found elsewhere!

Answer (score 3):

If the build is uploaded to appstore, then it will take some time normally. In the mean time You can see your newly uploaded build in the activity section under the version of the app with a processing label in brackets(see [image: screenshot]).

Once uploaded build with a version number and build number cannot be uploaded to appstore again.If you want to upload new build to appstore, then either change the version or build number and try again.

Comment: @JackD Okay. Then it may be an issue with the AppStore/iTunesConnect. Check once again for the build whether it has appeared in iTunesConnect and if not, go on with uploading new build.